# MySQL update all rows with value of that row changed by function

Tags: mysql, sql

The idea is to change all password column with same value but after MD5 function

password couldn't be null

```
| password |
|   val1   |
|   val2   |
...
|   valn   |
```

And updated table should be:

```
| password |
| MD5(val1)|
| MD5(val2)|
...
| MD5(valn)|
```

Any idea?

Comment: Basically you want the Passwords in the table to be stored as a MD5 hash value?

Answer (score 3):

```
update tableName 
set password = MD5(password) 
where 0 = 0
```

Something like this will work. You didn't specify table name. But this will set a new value in password column which will be MD5 function

**EDIT**: I've added a where clause to prevent the safe mode error.

I would just disable the safe mode in the client..

Comment: Table name is users but I get error:  You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: Yea safe mode will stop you from updating a table without a where clause. It's up to you to disable that . Or just do one user at a time

Comment: I disabled but it was a problem, I had to kill all the processes of MySQL with other tool. About where clause...than it wouldn't be automatic for all rows, right?

Comment: true, this was just an option. The error is only in your client so it don;t really matter. If you can't disable it and don't want the where clause just put where 0=0 this should work around your error

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current values of a row in an `UPDATE`. So something  simple as

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET password = md5(password);
```

should do it.

Comment: Error -> You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: @zelenooq: That's a client issue, has nothing to do with the statement per se. Do as it tells you and toggle the safe mode or use another client. Or try to tick it with some "true-for-all" `WHERE` clause like `WHERE 1 = 1`.